# What is the best practice for unit testing AngularJS modules kept in a self executable anonymous funcitons

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, chutzpah

I am looking for suggestions about the best practice around here in this scenario. I have created an angularjs SPA application and looking for building a unit test framework for it. I observed that I am not able to get the app object of the module because I have included all my JS files in self executing anonymous functions.

Here is my module for the application

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     var app = angular.module('app', []);
})();
```

Here is my unit test file to load app module

```
describe("App Model Load -> ", function () {
    beforeEach(module("app"));
    it("Check App object", function () {
        expect(app).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I found resolutions like using a namespace on the top and binding the app variable to the namespace, but it is no different from opening up the app variable globally. Any thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't need to write a test to verify that the app object exists.  You should only be testing the sub-modules that are added to the app object.

Comment: Yes, I got that but I just wrote it for explaining the scenario, it errors out in beforeEach step, in the above scenario.

Comment: If you call angular.module by specifying only first argument then, if module exist, you can retrieve it. In your unit test try this: 
var app = angular.module('app');expect(app).toBeDefined();

Comment: Hmmm this certainly works but I want to mock the app object here and not reinitialize it. Also, when I try var app then it cetainly comes as defined but I am not able to mock it

Comment: What do you mean by "mock module"? As Saikiran Sheshagiri mentioned you should mock parts of module (like services) not the whole module. Module is only a container.

Comment: Sorry, i meant tennisgent :)